# what is the best way to check whether the list is null or not before looping?

Tags: java, null, for-loop

I know it is a primitive question but I want to learn the smartest way.

I want to loop over the `ArrayList<Integer> intList` and it can be null. I have 2 ways of doing it

```
if(intList != null) {
     for(int i = 0; i < intList.size(); i++){
             System.out.println(intList.get(i));
     }
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; intList != null && i < intList.size(); i++){
     System.out.println(intList.get(i));
}
```

First way seems more pretty to me. What do you think? What are your implementations in that situation?

Excuse me, if it is duplicate question but I can't find one

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I would choose the first implementation as well because its intent is clearer.

Generally, I would try to avoid a `List` (or any other `Collection` object, really) being `null`. When evaluating a `List` (which is suddenly and unexpectedly `null`) you most probably want to abort before any processing takes place so either case of looping over the collection would not occur.

Comment: +1 agree first is clearer and avoiding a `List` being `null` to begin with. The method creating the `List` should consider returning `Collections.<Integer>emptyList()` if possible and appropriate.

Comment: The first is a common and simple idiom whilst the second is unusual and therefore requires extra time for a developer to work out why it is different. Go for the common and simple unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the first one, for the complete code segment will most likely to be:

```
if(intList != null) {
 for(int i = 0; i < intList.size(); i++){
         System.out.println(intList.get(i));
 }
}
else {
   //Do something here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We have one development rule in our company:

- If a function is written that returns a list or an array, *never return null*! Return an empty list or an empty Array in the case where there are no elements to return.

This can be done with minimal overhead, like here:

```
public List<String> getNames() {
    if( !loaded ) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    ...
}
```

If applied properly, you don't have to check for null-lists. We don't have to.

**EDIT:** Oh, and to come back to your question at hand: Use the forst variant, it is much clearer, and faster, because the null check only have to be done once (it might be that the compiler factors it out anyway, but in variant 1 you can be sure).

Comment: Item 43 in "Effective Java" (2nd edition) agrees with you: "Return empty arrays or collections, not null"

Comment: You can read a PDF of the chapter on generics (items 23 to 29 inclusive) via the link at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/

Comment: Thanks. I think I will buy a download version if I find one somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

i preffer the first one as mostly i use the first process

Answer (score 0):

To me the first option is clearer and easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

According to me first option should be preferred for its readability is better than second one, while the second one saves one extra line of code for you.

End of the day both are going to do same thing so its up to you, which code you want to use. I would suggest to stick to first as it is more developer friendly because of readability.

Answer (score 0):

The first form is more readable - the intent is much clearer.

The first form *may* also be faster, since the second form says to test that `intList` is not null **each time you go around the loop**.  (The JIT compiler *may* optimize away the unnecessary tests ... but why rely on this.)